# Declare type in InputField

Tags: inputfield, data-types

Is it possible to declare a `type` in `InputFunction` to only accept positive Integers as input?

I know i can create an `InputField` only allowing numbers and check if the value is a positive integer:

```
InputField[Dynamic[x], Number]
```

Then i could check the value later:

```
If[Positive@x && IntegerQ@x,...
```

But is it also possible to already limit the allowed input in the InputField to match those conditions? So `-` and `.` are not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To control the precise behavior of `InputFields` for various keyboard interactions is not exactly something where Mathematica shines, but there are some possbilities with which you can achieve what you want:

If you want to do certain checks of the user input you can do so with a second argument to `Dynamic`, which will not only work for `InputField` but also for other gui elements. Here is how you can only allow input which is larger than zero:

```
InputField[Dynamic[x, Function[If[# >= 0, x = #]]], Number]
```

you'll note that for invalid input this will just keep the old value. Here is a variation that will only allow values between 0 and 1 and change the input you give to the nearest value in that interval:

```
InputField[Dynamic[x, Function[x = Clip[#, {0, 1}]]], Number]
```

If you want to disable certain characters in the input, there are two ways (with many variations) which I know. You can either switch to a String `InputField` with `ContinuousAction->True` like this:

```
InputField[
  Dynamic[ToString[x],
    Function[x = ToExpression@StringReplace[#, {
      d : DigitCharacter :> d,
      _ :> ""
    }]]], 
  String, ContinuousAction -> True
]
```

again you can adopt the code in the second argument to `Dynamic` to meet your needs, but my experience is that this will often behave strange concerning focus and the cursor position.

The other possibility which is probably somewhat more limited but I think does behave much better is to only pass those keyboard events to the `InputField` which you want it to see, like so:

```
EventHandler[
  InputField[Dynamic[x], Number], 
  {
    {"KeyDown", "."} :> Null, 
    {"KeyDown", "-"} :> Null
  }, PassEventsDown -> False
]
```

note that I did set the `PassEventsDown` to `False` explicitly to make more clear what actually happens, but as it is the default setting you'd not necessarily need it. Of course you could combine this with a second argument for `Dynamic` to make more checks/restrictions.

Comment: I really like the EvenHandler solution. I'll try this out, but it already looks really promising.

Comment: yes, for exactly this problem it seems to be a good solution. Unfortunatly it isn't easy to generalize for more complicated cases...